# Difference between NEW and OLD trigger variables as JSON in pgsql

Tags: json, postgresql-9.3, hstore

I am using postgres 9.3 and implementing audit triggers to log changes in my tables. To know about the columns updated i need to take a diff between OLD and NEW trigger variables. I have achieved it using hstore. But hstore converts array type columns to string which needs extra handling. So any idea how can i do this using json?

Comment: json also converts everything to a string. Here is an example of an audit trigger using json: http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: but it does not converts array type column to list of strings. eg. [label1,label2] converts to {label1,label2} using hstore